# Group cohomology with coefficients in a permutation module (follow-up)

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

This is a follow-up question to [Group cohomology with coefficients in a permutation module](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255643/group-cohomology-with-coefficients-in-a-permutation-module) (which was for the case of a normal subgroup)

Let $A$ be an Abelian group, and let $G$ be a finite group which acts on a finite set $M$ (such that the orbit of any point in $M$ is $M$).
I can define a $G$-module (i.e. Abelian group with $G$-action) $A^M$, which is the set of functions from $M$ into $A$, and the $G$-action gets inherited from $M$.

Now, consider some $m_* \in M$, and let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ which leaves $m_*$ invariant. By restricting onto $H$ and $m_*$, I get a homomorphism in group cohomology from $\mathcal{H}^n(G, A^M) \to \mathcal{H}^n(H,A)$. Is it an isomorphism? If $H$ is a normal subgroup, then $A^M$ is the same as the co-induced module $A^G$ so I get an isomorphism by Shapiro's Lemma. But if $H$ is not normal then I'm not sure.

Comment: I was going to ask what examples you've checked, but instead I decided to check a few myself. GAP (specifically, Holt's algorithm "cohomolo") quickly computes H^2. It works out for the permutation modules for M12 and M24. Ellis's algorithm "HAP" can do higher degrees, but is harder (for me) to program with.

Comment: @Theo Johnson-Freyd If you will forgive my ignorance, what are "M12" and "M24"?

Comment: @DominicElse: I guess they must the simple groups discovered in the 19th century by Mathieu,  $M_{12}, M_{24}$. They are multiply transitive.

Comment: You would have been sure if you had bothered to read the wikipedia article on Shapiro's Lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%27s_lemma

Comment: @BenWebster I did read it (and Weibel too), but the co-induced module does not seem to be the same as the permutation module I defined unless $H$ is normal. Are you saying it is in fact the same?

Comment: (Specifically, the issue with identifying the co-induced module with the permutation module is that, as a function from $G$ into $A$, the co-induced module is constant on right cosets of $H$ -- whereas the set $M$ is naturally identified with the *left* cosets).

Comment: The coinduced module is the same as the permutation module. I'm not sure what you mean in your comment by "as a function from $G$ into $A$", but maybe you're confusing left and right actions? If $M$ is the set of left cosets, then $G$ naturally acts on $M$ on the left, but then the natural action of $G$ on $A^M$ is on the right, whereas Wikipedia and Weibel both use left modules when discussing Shapiro's Lemma.

Comment: @JeremyRickard $A^M$ is defined to be the set of functions $f : M \to A$. If   I have a left-action of $G$ on $M$ then I should have a left action on $A^M$ according to $(gf)(m) = f(gm)$. What am I missing here?

Comment: I quote: "When H is finite index in G, then the induced and coinduced representations coincide and the lemma is valid for both homology and cohomology."

Comment: @DominicElse You're missing the fact that the action on functions is defined by $(g\cdot f)(m)=f(g^{-1}m)$.  You can easily check that your formula doesn't respect group multiplication.  Since inverse switches left and right cosets, this also deals with your concern about left and right cosets.

Comment: @DominicElse As P Vanchinathan says, these are two of Mathieu's groups. They are sporadic groups with highly-transitive small permutation representations. They are pretty fast with to compute with, and so good ones to check conjectures on.